# When an elliptic curve is a quotient of $\mathbb{G}_a$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I want to know when an elliptic curve $E \rightarrow S$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{G}_a$.
 When $S$ is an analytic space, there is an exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow R^1 \mathbb{Z}^{\vee} \rightarrow e^{*} \omega_{E/S}^{\vee} \cong \mathbb{G}_a \rightarrow E \rightarrow 0$$ (even for abelian schemes). However, for a general scheme $S$, I think this cannot be true in general. If the exponential map is surjective (I don't know when this is true), there would be some exact sequence. Would it (the kernel) be some kind of lattice?

In the $p$-adic case, though, I think some version would be reasonable. Is there a generalization for $S$ not over the complex numbers? Any references or explanations on how to construct this kind of uniformization?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a $\mathbb{G}_m$-uniformization of $p$-adic analytic elliptic curves with bad reduction.  However, the exponential function isn't $p$-adically entire, so lifting to an additive uniformization seems difficult.

Comment: @S.Carnahan What about the exponential of the lie algebra? Is it surjective under some conditions?

Comment: The exponential function doesn't converge on the whole Lie algebra.  Even after restriction, I think surjectivity would require base change to some period ring.